# Not able to link opencv library during compilation

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw

I built opencv from github source by following along [this tutorial](https://zami0xzami.wordpress.com/2016/03/16/building-opencv-using-mingw-on-windows/), everything was successful but on compiling my sample program to draw a circle,

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main( )
{    
  // Create black empty images
  Mat image = Mat::zeros( 400, 400, CV_8UC3 );

  // Draw a line 
  line( image, Point( 15, 20 ), Point( 70, 50), Scalar( 110, 220, 0 ),  2, 8 );
  imshow("Image",image);

  waitKey( 0 );
  return(0);
}
```

I am getting error. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878160/function-not-declared-in-this-scope-error-in-compiling-opencv-code), I have to link the imported  libraries while compiling my program. But in my `MinGW/lib` folder there is no such file as `opencv_core.a` or `opencv_highgui.a`, instead I have `libopencv_core400.dll.a` and `libopencv_highgui400.dll.a`

[image]

so, if I try with options  `-lopencv_core`  and `-lopencv_highgui`

```
D:\Programs\CppProgramming>g++ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -std=c++11 OpenCVTest.cpp
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_core
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

or even with options `-llibopencv_core400` and -`llibopencv_highgui400`

```
D:\Programs\CppProgramming>g++ -llibopencv_core400 -llibopencv_highgui400 -std=c++11 OpenCVTest.cpp
C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnjHIL5.o:OpenCVTest.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)'
C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnjHIL5.o:OpenCVTest.cpp:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `cv::circle(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnjHIL5.o:OpenCVTest.cpp:(.text+0x1c2): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnjHIL5.o:OpenCVTest.cpp:(.text+0x1f6): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnjHIL5.o: bad reloc address 0x12 in section `.text$_ZN2cv11_InputArrayC2Ev[__ZN2cv11_InputArrayC2Ev]'
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Where can I find those libraries to link and compile my program successfully ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below command in the following order solved my compilation issue

```
g++ -std=c++11 OpenCVTest.cpp -llibopencv_core400 -llibopencv_highgui400 -llibopencv_imgproc400
```

Comment: for me, the correct links were -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc